# UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0301' in position 17: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python, csv, utf-8, cp1251

Пытаюсь спарсить веб-сайт, но при записи одной из страниц в csv-файл появляется ошибка:

```
File "E:\Python\main.py", line 102, in <module>
    writer.writerow(
  File "C:\Python39\lib\encodings\cp1251.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0301' in position 17: character maps to <undefined>
```

Вот мой код:

```
products_data = soup.find(class_='mzr-tc-group-table').find('tbody').find_all('tr')
for item in products_data:
    products_tds = item.find_all('td')

    title = products_tds[0].find('a').text
    calories = products_tds[1].text
    proteins = products_tds[2].text
    fats = products_tds[3].text
    carbohydrates = products_tds[4].text

    with open(f'data/{count}_{category_name}.csv', 'a', encoding = 'cp1251', newline='') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=";")
        writer.writerow(
            (
                title,
                calories,
                proteins,
                fats,
                carbohydrates
            )
        )
```

При смене кодировки на utf-8 данная ошибка пропадает, но в csv-файл записываются непонятные символы. Помогите пожалуйста как использовать кодировку для windows (cp1251) и при этом, чтоб не выскакивала данная ошибка.

Comment: Почему вы решили, что в csv записыаются непонятные символы? Скорее всего, то, чем вы смотрите csv не верно показывает юникод. И потом, если у вас уже есть юникод, работайте с ним. он как-то универсальней, чем cp1251

Comment: Можете попробовать для `csv.writer` указать `encoding = 'cp1251`. Скорее всего у вас входной файл в `UTF-8`, а выходной файл вы хотите видеть в родной виндовой кодировке.

Comment: @strawdog Я пользуюсь OC Windows, на ней кодировка "cp1251". Поэтому при использовании юникода у меня отображаются непонятные символы. CSV-файл просматриваю в excel.

Comment: @CrazyElf Так я же указал кодировку "cp1251". Да, хочу видеть документ именно в этой кодировке. Но в таком случае появляется ошибка, которую я указал выше. Хочу понять как используя данную кодировку не попасть под эту ошибку. Возможно как-то пропустить этот символ, но я не знаю как - новичок.

Comment: ну так символы юникода не могут по определению полностью транслироваться в cp1251. вот наоборот - можно. вам либо нужно проверять данные перед записью на предмет символов, что очень не очень, либо уже работать с юникодом

Comment: @strawdog Судя по тому, что юникод неправильно отображается у меня, то скорее воспользоваться первым вариантом. Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать.

Comment: `open(f'data/{count}_{category_name}.csv', 'a', encoding = 'cp1251', newline='', errors='replace')` - попробуйте так.

Comment: @strawdog Огромное спасибо, помогли, всё работает!